# How to replace all the occurrences of string start and end with pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have this string:

```
[image: alfa-romeo-giulia-quadrifoglio-2017-01.jpg]\r\n[image: downloadwww.jpg]\r\n\r\n\r\nEmail content With 2 Inline Attachments and 2 another attachments.\r\nTo : me \r\nBcc and Cc : me\r\n
```

I want to replace this pattern anywhere in the string:

```
[image: .....]
```

I am using

```
preg_match_all('/\[image:\](.*?)\=(.*?)\]\]/s', $input, $matches);
```

This code returns an empty array. Please help me to replace all occurrences of it.

Comment: You do not have `]]` in your string. None of those tags contain `=` either. If you need to replace, why use `preg_match_all`? Try `preg_replace('/\[image:[^]]*]/', '', $input);`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ZZZtsU

Comment: Im bad in regex. this was a try. How would I go about accomplishing this?  Could you provide a sample?

Comment: I have, see https://ideone.com/ZZZtsU

Comment: Thanks alot @Wiktor Stribiżew....  this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all` extracts strings from a larget string, and to replace, you need to use [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Your string does not contain `]]`, nor the `=` char.

You may use

```
preg_replace('/\[image:[^]]*]/', '', $input)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ZZZtsU)

The `\[image:[^]]*]` pattern matches

- `\[image:` - a `[image:` substring
- `[^]]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.